# geopy.distance.vincenty gives different result for radians and degrees

Tags: python, geopy

I run the `geopy.distance.vincenty()` function of Python in the same coordinates, one time in degrees and then in radians and I get completely different results.

```
print(geopy.distance.vincenty((0.88802*180.0 / math.pi, 0.0780654*180.0 / math.pi),
                              (0.888019*180.0 / math.pi, 0.0780669*180.0 /math.pi )).m)
```

I get 8.787072619249342

and when I do it in radians

```
print(geopy.distance.vincenty((0.88802, 0.0780654), (0.888019, 0.0780669)).m)
```

I get 0.2002536292651726.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is expecting values in degrees, so the first result is correct. You'll get the same answer if you convert the second set of coordinates to degrees, e.g. with `math.degrees()` or `np.degrees()`:

```
import numpy as np
geopy.distance.vincenty((np.degrees((0.88802, 0.0780654)),
                         np.degrees((0.888019, 0.0780669)).m
                        )
```

I'm looking at [the example in the documentation](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#geopy.distance.vincenty), and also at [the code](https://github.com/ulope/geopy/blob/master/geopy/distance.py#L202-L205). (By the way, note that it says `vincenty()` is deprecated.)